# How to pass values through classes

Tags: java, javafx

I have a subtotal of how many tickets a user is buying in a cinema system (from the TicketsPageController), however I need this to be printed in a text field in the OrderSummary class, however it is only printing 'null', not too sure why?

Here is the method in the TicketsPageController:

```
public static Double getTicketsPrice() {
        return ticketsPrice;
    }
```

and here is the method I'm passing in the OrderSummary:

```
public class OrderSummary extends TicketsPageController{

 public void initialize() {
        displaySummary.setText(String.valueOf(ticketPrice));
        displaySummary.setText(String.valueOf(snackPrice));

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem. Otherwise there are a hundred different reasons why this might be happening.

Comment: What other information should I put in, as this is part of a much bigger program?

Comment: We can't see where/when the values for `ticketPrice` and `snackPrice` are being set or where they are coming from. Try using a debugger and setting breakpoints to see what your variables are set to at different points of your code execution.

Comment: Please read the link that Jason posted. It will provide you with some excellent tips on how to include all the details we would need. You could also read the guide on [ask] good questions here.